# Flutter runs only from C:\Windows\system32> folder

Tags: flutter

I have just installed flutter 3 on my Windows machine. However, it gives out the following error when running any flutter command.

> `'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.`

However, when I run `flutter doctor` in the C:\Windows\system32 folder, whether using administrative privileges, I get the following output:

> `Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):`

> `[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889], locale en-US)`

> `[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)`

> `[√] Chrome - develop for the web`

> `[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Professional 2022 17.3.3)`

> `[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)`

> `[√] VS Code (version 1.71.0)`

> `[√] Connected device (3 available)`

> `[√] HTTP Host Availability`

> `• No issues found!`

Flutter projects also do not open in Android Studio.

Somebody, please help.
Please help me with how I can run flutter.

Answer (score 1):

add to your PATH c:\windows\system32
I had the same problem and that's how I solved it